# How to pass a variable to config file in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova

In the `app.js` file I have `.config` which has states for all the navigation urls. I want to pass a variable to `container.html` file which is the config file, The state for base url is as follows:

```
     // setup an abstract state for the tabs directive
        .state('tab', {
        url: "/tab",
        abstract: true,
       templateUrl: "templates/container.html"
     })
```

I want to pass a variable called division which will have value either "agriculture" or "construction" and based on that variable I want to do further operations. Can anybody help me I am pretty new to angularJS. Additional info: I am working on cordova, angularJS, taffy for a mobile app. Thanks in advance.
I want the url to be something like `/tab/:division` or `templates/container.html/division` which i will later be able to use in the `container.html` file.

Comment: Is it possible for you to use angular ui router? If so, you can have a look here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#url-Parameters

Comment: yes that is exactly what I am using. Now if you see the example they have given for basic url, I want to pass a variable to that url. Any idea about how should I do that. because if you notice there is no controller function attached to that. and the `container.html` contains sidebar which has a couple of navigation items which i want to hide on the basis of that passed variable.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you don't have a controller attached to this? Without it, you're pretty much going to have a static page.

Comment: Right that is a static page, which has a sidebar navigation with a couple of href's. I finally figured out, that still had an access to `$root` scope so I attached division variable to that and boom! thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
// setup an abstract state for the tabs directive
        .state('tab', {
        url: "/tab/:division",
        abstract: true,
       templateUrl: "templates/container.html",
       controller:'ctnCtrl'
     })

//controller
.controller('ctnCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams) {
//get the value from url
$scope.division=$stateParams.division;

});


//in your container.html you can read the variable
<span>{{division}}</span>
```